# how to analyze bijectivity/injectivity/surjectivity of this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have a function:

$\ f: \Bbb N² \mapsto\Bbb N \\ 
\ \ (n,p) \mapsto2^p(2n+1)$

And I need to examine its injectivity/surjectivity/bijectivity

This is how I have tried to do:

Let's $ u \in \Bbb N $ then:

$ f(n,p) = u \\ \Leftrightarrow 2^p(2n+1) = u \\ \Leftrightarrow n = \frac{u}{2^{p+1}} - \frac{1}{2} \ and \ p = \frac{ln(\frac{u}{2n+1}) }{ln(2)} \ if \ u \neq 0$

So I conclude that $f$ is not injective because there is more than one solution ( $n$ equals something depending on $p$, and same for $p$ depending on $n$)

And it is not surjective because there is no solution for $f(n,p) = 0$

Am I doing right ?

Comment: You're wrong, simply because you do not check if the values found for  $n$ and $p$ are natural numbers.

Comment: let u be an odd number then what would happen?

Comment: You're right I've totally missed that ... But how can I check if n and p natural ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is bijective from $\mathbf N^2$ onto $\mathbf N^{\color{red}*}=\mathbf N\smallsetminus \{0\}$.

- It is injective: indeed, if $2^p(2n+1)=2^{p'}(2n'+1)$, we can suppose  $p'\ge p$. Rewrite the equality as $\;2n+1=2^{p'-p}(2n'+1)$. As $2n+1$ is odd, this implies $p'-p=0$, whence $2n+1=2n'+1$, so that $n=n'$.
- It is surjective on $\mathbf N^*$: for any integer $N>0$, let $p$ the greatest power of $2$ that divides $N$: this means $N=2^pN'$  for some *odd* $N'$, i.e. there is a $n\ge 0$ such that $N'=2n+1$.

*Note 1:* For a bijection onto $\mathbf N$, consider the function $\;(n,p)\longmapsto 2^p(2n+1)-1$.

*Note 2:* One can deduce from this bijection a total order on $\mathbf N^*$, different from the usual order: just consider for any $N_1, N_2$ the reverse lexicographical order on the associated pairs $(n_1, p_1)$ and $(n_2,p_2$) and say 
$$N_1 < N_2\iff (p_1<p_2)\enspace\text{or}\enspace(p_1=p_2\enspace\text{and}\enspace n_1 < n_2).$$
Thus $\;3<9<2<4<12$.

Answer (score 1):

The condition for a function to be one one is $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ implies $x_1=x_2$..

$f(x)\neq 0$ for $x\neq 0$ is not the condition for one one function..

It is not clear if the one which you found for $n,p$ are natural numbers...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the prime factorisation of $u\ne 0$. $u$ can always be written uniquely as a product $2^pv$ where $v$ is odd. This forces $n=(v-1)/2$. Hence we have infectivity. Unfortunately $0$ is not attained, so we do not have surjectivity.

Comment: Not exactly: $0$ is not attained.

Comment: You are correct, will edit